# Using WPF Path Data in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, wpf, pathgeometry

Is there any way to re-use Path data created in the mini-language for use with the WPF Path element in ASP.NET? Or is the Path mini-language exclusive to WPF?

I have a Win8 app that has a number of path geometry strings in the format "M10,110 L30,90 M50,110 L30,90", etc. I would really like to re-use these in a new ASP.NET website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, this is the SVG path syntax. e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is an easy way to reuse 'WPF' path in ASP.NET. What exactly are you trying to do? Perhaps, reuse the shape image would be the best way to go.

Comment: I edited the question to explain the rationale behind the request. I was hoping someone might have found a way to re-use the existing paths...but I'm not expecting an affirmative response.